# Domain Model for wiki type site

Tags: dns, versioning, wiki

I'm looking for something along the lines of a Domain Model for a Wikipedia style site. I'm interested to learn more about how it works under the hood, and how I can borrow some of it's versioning principals for use in my own products.

Please note I am not looking for a versioning class or plugin that I can incorporate into my project. I would rather some high level literature that explains the objects in the domain and how they interact with each other to create wiki style platform.

I've done a lot of work myself in crafting a domain model, but I'm at a point where I would like some reinforcement that what I'm doing is on the right path.